# Change path for certain actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change only paths to certain actions of my controller.

For example I have the following actions on my `ExampleController`.

- New
- Create
- Edit
- Destroy
- Update
- Index
- Show

I would love to have my `new`, `create`, `delete` and `update` actions on the path `/admin/example/` and have the rest (`index` and `show`) available on `/example`.

Of course I can do this by adding new routes like :

`match "/admin/example/:id/destroy", to: "example#destroy", via: "destroy"`

But I do not want to do that for every controller. I tried doing the following:

```
scope '/admin' do
    resources :example, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
end
resources :example, only: [:index, :show]
```

This seems to work, but whenever I want to create a new `example` object, it gives me the following error:

`No route matches [POST] "/example"`

It also ends up on the URL `/example` instead of `/admin/example`

Am I on the right track or am I doing something completely wrong here. I would like to keep all my `example` based actions in the same controller.

**Update**: I tried to the following based on the answer of @apneadiving:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @example] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

But his results in a `NoMethodError`, while rendering the form, with the message:

`undefined method 'admin_example_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff3cceeb778>:0x007ff3cbe85820>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give details to your form.

`form_for @post` is looking for `[POST] "/example"`

So use:

```
form_for [:admin, @post]
```

Comment: This causes an error, I updated my question with updated information. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: oh Isee, you're using scope and not namespace... mmm, why do you keep actions in a single one controller when you have admin/standard user logic?

Comment: Well I protect actions using a before_action method and would like to keep all actions for an object in a single controller. It's actually just a cosmetic change (nicer URLs).

Comment: you'll end up with conditional before filters instead of having a nice admin_controller with proper access restrictions, looks bad

Comment: Based on your comments, I am now splitting stuff up into two controllers. This might indeed be the right way to go.

Comment: create an admin controller, then make it the ancestor of all controllers in admin